# Trying to filter sql database for multiple conditions in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I'm trying to combine the following filters into one step, but can't figure it out.

```
historic_CK <- tbl(Con.corp,in_schema("hsdb", "tbl_corp_biology_number")) %>% 
  filter(sql("Reference LIKE 'CK%'")) %>% 
  collect()

historic_BB <- tbl(Con.corp,in_schema("hsdb", "tbl_corp_biology_number")) %>% 
  filter(sql("Reference LIKE 'BB%'")) %>% 
  collect()
```

I've tried various different filter lines like

```
filter(grepl('BB|CK', Reference))
```

For security purposes I can't share the login to the database and am not sure how to supply sample data. I'm hoping maybe someone can provide a solution without these. Thanks.

Comment: You can just use an OR clause in your SQL statement: `REFERENCE LIKE 'BB%' OR REFERENCE LIKE 'CK%'`, or you can use an or-operator (`|`) within `filter()`. What didn't work about the line that you tried?